# Perfect forwarding in this case

Tags: c++11, perfect-forwarding

I am currently reading about perfect forwarding and it states that the purpose of perfect forwarding is to pass lvalues as lvalues and rvalues as rvalues. So I am using the following example to understand perfect forwarding . The `foo` object here has has a copy and move cnstr and it also has a copy and move assignment operator.

```
void mfoo(foo arg)
{
    .......
}


template<typename T>
void relay(T&& arg)
{
    mfoo(std::forward<T>(arg));
}


//Start here
foo f;
relay(std::move(f));
```

Now I am testing this code in VS2012 and the move constructor is called only once . I was expecting it to be called twice. I would appreciate it if someone could explain this to me.
I expected the first move constructor to be called at relay and the next move constructor to be called at mfoo

Comment: Where do you expect the move constructor to be called?

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: *"to be called at relay and the next move constructor to be called at mfoo"* Do you mean in the lines `relay(std::move(f));` and `mfoo(std::forward<T>(arg));`?

Comment: yes. Those are the lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Start here
foo f; // default-initialize `f`, call the default constructor
relay(std::move(f));
```

- `std::move(f)` does the same as `static_cast<foo&&>(f)`, so it actually doesn't "do" anything; it merely produces an rvalue expression ("`f` is treated as an rvalue").
- `relay( std::move(f) )` instantiates `void relay<foo>(foo&& arg)` and calls this function. The parameter is a reference and reference-compatible with the argument, hence no constructor is called.

---

```
mfoo(std::forward<T>(arg))
```

- `std::forward<T>(arg)` yields `arg` as an lvalue if `T` is an lvalue reference, or as an rvalue if `T` is not an lvalue reference. I.e., for `T == foo&&`, it does the same as `std::move(arg)`. No constructor is called.
- `mfoo(..)` finally calls `mfoo`, which takes its argument *by value*. This causes a copy or move, depending on the type and the value category of the argument expression.

As our argument expression here is an rvalue, the move constructor will be called (if existent and accessible).

Comment: The mnemonic I use is "`std::move` does not move and `std::forward` does not forward".